# PowerShell Emailing Arrays

Tags: arrays, email, powershell

I'm having issues with the way an array loses its formatting when it is emailed and viewed in outlook 2013

The formatted array looks like this in PowerShell

```
vServer                                          State             Connection                                                          
-------                                          -----             ----------                                                          
vServer-LB-1                                     UP                0                                                                   
vServer-LB-2                                     DOWN              0                                                                   
vServer-LB-3                                     UP                0                                                                   
vServer-LB-4                                     UP                0                                                                   
vServer-LB-5                                     UP                0                                                                   
vServer-LB-6                                     UP                2
```

This is how I formatted the array (I have tried to email the unformatted array, but it is still wrong)

```
$formatserver =  @{Expression={$_.name};Label="vServer";width=48}, `
                 @{Expression={$_.state};Label="State";width=17}, `
                 @{Expression={$_.establishedconn};Label="Connection"}

$Array = $server | Format-Table $formatserver
```

However, when emailed (not quite like this, but its not formatted correctly).

> vServer                                          State             Connection
>   -------                                          -----             ----------
>   vServer-LB-1                               UP                0
>   vServer-LB-2                                DOWN              0
>   vServer-LB-3                               UP                0
>   vServer-LB-4                                UP                0
>   vServer-LB-5                                  UP                0
>   vServer-LB-6              UP                2

Here is the code for emailing

```
$from = 'Reporting <Support@Me.com>'
$to = 'me@me.com'
$subject = 'Report'
$body = $Array | Out-String
$smtpServer = 'mail.me.com'

$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $subject, $body)
#$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Please note I have tried many combinations of `| out-string`and  `$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<pre>` tag in `HTML` to keep the spacing in your emails.

```
$body = $Array | Out-String | %{"<pre>"+$_+"</pre>"}
```

Make sure that you set `IsBodyHTML` as `$true`.

**Note**: Table formats a limited to the buffers of your `PowerShell` Shell/Console. So if your table width is more that the buffer width on your Shell/Console the table will not be shown in full.

To get round this you can set your shell buffer at the start of your script with the following:

```
$pshost = get-host
$pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui
$newsize = $pswindow.buffersize
$newsize.height = 3000
$newsize.width = 1500
$pswindow.buffersize = $newsize
```

Or go to `File >> Properties` on your Shell/Console, and change the following property.

[image]